# Render ARCore in cardboard

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, virtual-reality, arcore, google-vr

I tried to render ARCore stereoscopically through cardboard.  Due to the misalignment between the field of view of the ARCore camera and VR, the object appears to be not being tracked.

To sort this out, I referred to this [blog](https://medium.com/@jon_54445/augmented-reality-for-mobile-vr-headsets-adc6d5ed11fe) and implemented it by using a barrel distortion shader. However, it doesn't render stereoscopically.

Is there any other fix for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***For stereo-vision you need two View Controllers i.e. two `ArFragments`, each running at 60 fps***. Ideally you need a frame rate 120 fps but it's impossible in ARCore at this time.

[image]

> `Barrel distortion` is just a special type of a warped distortion of a view.

Also, for robust stereo experience you should shift views only along X-axis and **never along Y-axis**. In real life an effective distance between two camera lens is `64`-`200` mm.

For further details look at [Technicolor Paper: 15 Stereo Issues](https://3dvision-blog.com/4261-technicolor-certifi3d-program-and-the-15-point-3d-issues-checklist/).

And there are other visual implementations for stereo:

[image]

[image]

It's up to you which one is more comfortable for watching.

Comment: Thank you!  Isnt it possible to align the fov of both?

Comment: Sometimes, even at production stage it's very difficult. All stereo videos go to a post production. But if you make a fake stereo – it's ok (especially for AR app).

Comment: I have made a fake stereo using barrel distortion shader . But isnt there a better implementation so far?

Comment: What do you mean saying "better implementation" ?

Comment: instead of using barrel distortion shader, isn't there any other better implementation?

Comment: You may use it or may not. It's just an appearance of your view.

Comment: But I suppose that a `barrel warping` is the most comfortable for stereo vision in a cardboard.

Comment: I updated the answer. Just added two more pictures.